# getting Error "Exception clearing maxRows/queryTimeOut" Inspite of wait_timeout = 28800

Tags: mysql, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

Need help for resolving the following error by Sonar-runner:

```
13:57:55.705 WARN  - exception clearing maxRows/queryTimeout
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
```

.
.
.
.
.

```
13:57:55.707 WARN  - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
13:57:55.708 ERROR - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 3,765,195 milliseconds ago.
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 3 milliseconds ago.
```

MySQL Configuration:

```
mysql> show global variables like '%timeout%';  


interactive_timeout= 28800
wait_timeout = 28800
```

JDBC Connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://usaus020013srv.us002.siemens.net:3306/sonartest?enableQueryTimeouts=false&amp;autoReconnet=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
```

There are already threads which suggest that change the wait_timeout to a sufficiently big value, but I already have it set to 28800 which is 8 hours.

Regards,
Girish Joshi

Comment: If you are executing some queries those are transferring heavy data then also check max_allowed_packet variable setting.

Comment: @ZafarMalik : The max_allowed_packet is already set to 100 MB. Other threads suggest that in such a case the exception would be something like "com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (1807198 > 1048576)"  in the logs. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: try to set max_allowed_packet as 256MB temporarily to check this issue even if heavy queries are known then you can set it only in session for that module...if after setting it your issue resolved then at least we know the issue..then we can identify the problematic query and optimize this..and again set this variable normal should be between 64MB to 128MB...

Comment: This question relates to this [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651290/getting-exception-clearing-maxrows-querytimeout-on-sonarqube-4-5-1). I would start by profiling a little bit what happens on Mysql side because indeed, 8 hours this is far too long.